# PDO/PHP Script Query Database (Game Server baning system)

Tags: php, pdo

The Database structure:

- Name: person who the offense is against
- Reason: reason given for punishment
- Admin: who issued the punishment
- ID: PK
- Type: 1,2,3,4,5

type 3 : kick
type 0: ban

The way it's setup is once the player is given a punishment it will add a new row to the database. I'm trying to create a PHP script where players can enter their usernames on the website (their username=name field in database and it will show all the offenses on their account.

What i have so far:

```
$name = $_GET["username"];

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=server', 'username', 'pass');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM logs WHERE name = ' . $conn->quote($name));

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I'm not sure about where i go from here in terms of displaying the data if the above is even correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM logs WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($_GET["username"]));
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<table>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$row['type']?></td>
    <td><?=$row['admin']?></td>
    <td><?=$row['reason']?></td>
  </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: either you don't have error reporting on, or there is no data for the passed $_GET["username"] in the table